# Should I have a global object, javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am building a library for educational purposes; I have a lot of modules in my library.

One of my modules is needed a lot throughout my application. Is it better to store this object in a singleton global object that can be referenced from inside other objects that need it, or feed it into every object that needs it as a property?

I know this might have many opinionated answers, but it is still a question with which I am at a crossroads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695832/dependency-injection-vs-managed-dependencies-vs-global-object

Comment: Having a global object instance is not the same as having a singleton.

Comment: Can you provide an example code of the cases imagined and usages of such?

Comment: If it's an object you'll be accessing a lot, just throw it in the global namespace (with a unique name of course). And when you reference it, just make sure to use window.obj instead of just obj to make lookups faster.

Comment: Ideally, try to have one global object, and then hang all your modules on that.  Ie, `var App = { Modules: {} };` and then `App.Modules.Foo = _whatever_;`

Comment: @GJK I do this already as I went down the second route. I didn't know if it made sense though to feed it into the other modules?

Comment: Personally, I usually do what's easier. If this object is accessed in quite a few places and it's too much to keep passing around the reference, make it global. Just don't make too many things global. I tend to stick to around 10 to 15 global vars max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mention as your second option, is essentially that of dependency injection.  As such you have the inherent benefit of the testability of your code by mocking the injected object.

You also can thus avoid a global pollution as much as possible if this module does not need to be externally accessible to "other" 3rd party modules.  If you can inject it into all of your own modules then you should have no need to expose it publicly.

That is my take, bringing higher level design patterns into the Javascript world will only be to our betterment, and dependency injection is very highly thought of.